# 2-way polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a two-way polymorphic association.

I have `Assignments` and `Resources` and they each can have one of a wikipage, weblink, or file.

So a wikipage would `belong_to :assignment` or a `Resource` and an `Assignment` would `have_one` `contentable` (wikipage, weblink, or file).

Any idea on how to set it up?

UPDATE

This is my curent thought.  Since I will not look up assignments or resources from wikipages/web links/files, I will make assignments and resources belong to a contentable so that the foreign key and type will be in the assignments and resources table.  This will allow me to get the contentable from the assignment and resource class through the association.  Wikipages etc. will not have an association Which is okay because I don't need it.